# How to configure start up script on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance for IPython Notebook

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

By following the tutorial from [Running an iPython Notebook Server on AWS - EC2 Instance](http://blog.impiyush.me/2015/02/running-ipython-notebook-server-on-aws.html)

I successfully configured the ipython notebook server on AWS EC2 instance, also I found that to use `matplotlib` module I have to `ssh -X` to the instance and then run:

```
nohup ipython notebook --profile=nbserver
```

and then set

```
%matplotlib inline
```

in the ipython notebook connected through https in the browser.

Now I want to automate the whole process so that I can directly open the browser to use the ipython notebook when starting an instance, just like the [RStudio AMI created by Louis Aslett](http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/), so I tried:

```
crontab -e
```

then I add the following line to the end of this file

```
@reboot nohup ipython notebook --profile=nbserver
```

But but when I reboot this instance this command won't work. Also I don't know how to enable X11 forward in the start up script so that I can use `matplotlib` to plot. Can someone help me with this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Cron doesn't know your environment variables. So when you run ipython, it doesn't know where to find it from. To resolve;

First type

```
which ipython
```

then change this with the ipython part of your code

```
@reboot nohup /home/ubuntu/anaconda/bin/ipython notebook --profile=nbserver
```